# How to generate xls file from command line in Linux?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export-to-excel

I need to automatically update some price lists in Excel on my site on a daily basis. I used PHPExcel for that, but it takes a lot of memory (about 900 Mb) to generate 1 file with only 40000 lines and 11 columns, which is not available on my Linux hosting server. All Google results point to PHPExcel only. I wonder if there is any command line utility which allows to do the same thing, but consuming less memory, so I could run it on my Linux server using cron? I need to use some formatting and formulas in my Excel file, this makes CSV and HTML into non-options.

Of course, I may connect to MySQL from a Windows Server machine, generate Excel files in actual Excel there and then upload them to the server, but this option seems quite hacky for me.

**Added:**
I'm now deciding between PERL, Python and Java modules, choosing the one which consumes less resources on large files and is easier to use; any comment on this topic is welcome.
Also any other solutions are accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option to me was to use [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) library. Though I never wrote anything on python, it took me only a couple of hours to actually make the things work with it and it works much faster, than PHPExcel and consumes less memory (about 300 Mb on my largest file, comparing to 900 Mb for php). But if you are looking for the solution of similar problem, tools, provided in the other answers, may suite your need as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using java and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

It has good performance, even better then MS Office interop assemblies on windows (based on my own experience).

Also it has a big community of users.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that option!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your page you could just try to build an xlsx file by hand.  The xlsx specification is really complex but I've seen examples to create very simple tables.

Perhaps this [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-an-xml-file-into-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-this-technique/6163451) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I have had really good results using PERL and John McNamara's module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel to generate all sorts of fine spreadsheets.  But it takes programming.

Comment: Was your spreadshee large? Did it take much time and memory to generate?

Comment: Yes, some of these spreadsheets had tens of tabs, tens of thousands of rows, and were several megabytes in size.  The memory usage was on the order of the size of the final spreadsheet file, and the generation time was dominated by the SQL queries used to retrieve the data. Fairly straightforward deal, runnable from command lines in Linux or Windows with a PERL system installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try building it in [Templater](http://templater.info/) on Java from ResultSet. We are in process of updating site with more Java examples, but code would look something along this.

ITemplaterDocument doc = Configuration.Factory.Open(file);
doc.process(resultSet);
doc.flush();

Comment: It seems very easy to use, I should check about performance. Thanks!